# Adapter.getView is never called Android Studio

Tags: java, android, multithreading, adapter

Sadly my getView method is never called using a custom adapter, I think it has to do something with the Thread.
I need this Thread to not get an Exception because I cant do Network Activity in the Main Thread obviously. Maybe there is a better option for this.
This is my first Project mit API's so I still need to learn a lot! Thanks for your answers!

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Schedule> races;
    startpage_lv_adapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startPage(2020);
        ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.raceList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        if(races == null){
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        adapter = new startpage_lv_adapter(races, MainActivity.this);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void startPage(final int year) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Ergast ergast = new Ergast(year, 100, Ergast.DEFAULT_OFFSET);
                try {
                    races = ergast.getSchedules();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < races.size(); i++) {
                    Schedule race = races.get(i);

                    if (Date.valueOf(race.getDate()).before(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())) {
                        races.set(i, null);
                    }
                }
                races.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(null));
                int i = races.size();
                if (races.size() == 0) {
                    startPage(year+1);
                }

            }
        });
        thread.start();



    }

}


public class startpage_lv_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Schedule> races;
    private Context context;

    public startpage_lv_adapter(List<Schedule> races, Context context) {
        this.races = races;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return races.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return races.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview_events_detail, parent, false);
        String basicURL = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/";
        String country = races.get(position).getCircuit().getLocation().getCountry();
        String extendURL = "?fields=alpha2Code";
        try {
            HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = Unirest.get(basicURL+country+extendURL)
                    .asString();
             country = httpResponse.getBody().split(":")[1].replace('}', ' ').replace('"', ' ').trim();
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_countryFlag);
        TextView countryText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_countryName);
        TextView roundText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_roundNumber);
        basicURL = "https://www.countryflags.io/";
        extendURL = "/flat/64.png";
        Picasso.get().load(basicURL+country+extendURL);
        countryText.setText(races.get(position).getCircuit().getLocation().getCountry());
        roundText.setText("Round "+ position);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set adapter after initializing it (set initial value to it) not before, so move this line `lv.setAdapter(adapter);` after `adapter = new startpage_lv_adapter(races, MainActivity.this);` , I wonder how your app doesn't crash :D

```
adapter = new startpage_lv_adapter(races, MainActivity.this);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```